# MYSQL and PHP Need to add echo to a table on same page

Tags: php

I need to add an echo on a php page to a table i created on the same page to cross insert it onto a different SQL DB

The following is my code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","****","****");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("****", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members
WHERE member_msisdn='$slusername'");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Membership</th>
<th>Number</th>
<th>Registration Date</th>
<th>End Date</th>
<th>Copy of ID</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
echo "<td><center>" . $row['member_id'] . "</td>";   
echo "<td><font color=blue>" . $row['member_msisdn'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['asdate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['aedate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['attid'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?></div>
        <div class="Notes"><strong><br>
          Emergency Contact Numbers:</strong><br>
          <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","****","****");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("****", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members a INNER JOIN recipients b ON a.member_id =     
b.member_id WHERE member_msisdn=$slusername");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Number</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Surname</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
echo "<td><font color=blue>" . $row['recipient_msisdn'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['recipient_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['recipient_surname'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
        </div>
        <p>
          <label for="member_id"></label>
          <input type="text" name="member_id" id="member_id"> // here i need the    
member_id of members to be printed so i can have it entered into another table on same    
sql DB
        </p>
       <p><br>
        </p>
      </div></td>
```

Basically on the top section i echo the member_id but i need it to be inputed in the table member_id by itself and then by action placed on the SQL DB

Comment: Where you have your comment ("here i need the member_id of members..."), are you saying you need the resultset of `members.member_id` from the first database, and not the second?

Comment: Yes that is correct I want to print the info from the first database there and insert it into the second database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, well you're 99% of the way there. Here are some things to do:

- You're opening and closing your database connections separately. I suggest you open them together at the start, and close them together at the end
- The variable for your database handle in each case thus must be different. I suggest `$con1` and `$con2`, but that's up to you.
- Rather than `mysql_select_db` before each query, just do `mysql_query($sql, $con1)` (substituting the connection variable as appropriate). This makes it clearer which statement connects to what database.

From there, it is then easy to write an extra query at the end to read from the first database again, so you can put it in a set of `<input>` tag values.

---

Aside: your coding will become much easier if you try to separate out your "business logic" (how it works) from your "view" (what it looks like). A good start (for the first bit of your code) might look like this:

```
<?php
// This is the "logic" section, so we indent carefully, and get our
// variables ready for the "view" to consume
$con1 = mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "****");
if (!$con1)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Don't be afraid to wrap lines like this - makes them more readable,
// and means less h-scrolling in your IDE
$result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_msisdn='$slusername'",
    $con1
);
?>

<!-- This is our 'view' section, which we write in proper HTML, rather
than blobs of HTML trapped inside our echo statements -->
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Membership</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Registration Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th>Copy of ID</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- One useful convention is to use the colon form of loops for views
  - it is generally thought of as neater -->
  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <!-- You forgot to open (tr) -->
    <tr>
      <!-- Note! Always close tags you've opened -->
      <!-- (center) and (font) are deprecated anyway, use CSS instead -->
      <td><center>
        <?php echo $row['member_id'] ?>
      </center></td>
      <td><font color="blue">
        <?php echo $row['member_msisdn'] ?>
      </font></td>
      <td><center>
        <?php echo $row['asdate'] ?>
      </center></td>
      <td><center>
        <?php echo $row['aedate'] ?>
      </center></td>
      <td><center>
        <?php echo $row['attid'] ?>
      </center></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endwhile ?>
</table>

<!-- You can do connection closing and other cleanup here -->
```

Now, we get the benefit of syntax colouring in our *real* HTML, and PHP is just opened for tiny one-line statements. Much cleaner! I've indented it better too, which helped reveal the missing opening (tr) and missing closing (font, center) tags. See the code for comments I've added.

Comment: Ok i have done the cleanup a little looks better as well but problem i still cannot call the member_id into a field automatically printing it there for me to move it into another sql

Comment: That gives me nothing new to respond to. Perhaps add a link to a pasteboard (e.g. pastie.org) of your new code?